# How to rebase via pull request in Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-flow

Our team uses Bitbucket for collaboration and we have enabled pull-request workflow for `master` and `develop` branches. This means these two branches become read-only and cannot be `push`ed to. They can only be changed via creating a branch from them, making changes, pushing the branch, creating a pull-request from it and having another team member review it and merge the request on top of the original branch via BitBucket interface.

Unfortunately, when creating the merge request, BitBucket interface defaults to `master`, instead of the actual parent branch of current feature branch, and occasionally team members forget to change it to `develop` before creating the merge request or approving it. This has led to `master` and `develop` diverging from each other and now we cannot merge `develop` on top of `master` when we want to release.

If `develop` was not forbidden to `push` to, I could `rebase` it from `master`, apply all non-existing commits, and then `push --force` to make it a descendant from the tip of `master`.

I tried branching from `develop` and `rebase`ing it from `master` to have it include all commits from `master` and then send it as a merge-request to `develop`, but there are merge conflicts and BitBucket refuses to allow it to merge.

Now I'm stuck. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: can you share your git graph of develop and working branch? ideally, your problem should not occur.

Answer (score 1):

You can checkout to your `master` branch and take the lastest from `master` via

```
git pull --rebase origin master
```

Since you're forbidden to push into `master` and `develop` both, you can try checking out into new branch from `master` via

```
git checkout -b <new-branch-name>
```

Now you'll be on , rebase from your `develop` branch

```
git rebase develop
```

Now you'll have all commits which are in master and develop, you can delete the `develop` branch via

```
git branch -D develop
git push -d origin develop
```

and push the  via

```
git push -u origin <new-branch-name>
```

and raise a Pull Request from  to master.
Hopefully, this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try fast forward option during merge? It actually helped me to keep tree cleaner.

[image]